# What does "dynamically modify resource tables" exactly mean in Android Application

Tags: android, android-resources, android-app-bundle

Can someone explain, what does "modify resource tables" exactly mean in below point. I have came across this in Android App bundles "known issues" section. This would help me further in my project migration to Android App bundles.

"If you use tools that dynamically modify resource tables, Applications generated from app bundles might behave unexpectedly. So, when building an app bundle, it is recommended that you disable such tools."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resource table is the file named `resources.arsc` in an APK. Some tools may edit this file after it's been generated by the build system for various purposes.

Because the Android App Bundles contains this file under another format, these tools may not work if they haven't added support for the App Bundle. That's what this message means.